# Media Player Classic Home Cinema stops on MKV

Tags: windows-8, ffmpeg, media-player-classic

Media Player Classic Home Cinema stops on MKV. It goes to "stop" mode after file open. Unable to run playing. No error messages generated.

MPC-HC version: 1.6.7.7114 (9eb64ec) 64 bit

Compiler version: MSVC 2010 SP1

Ffmpeg compiler version: MinGW-w64 GCC 4.7.3

Windows Version: x64 8 prof

**MKV samples**

Sample 1:

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 1024x576 25fps ...
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch 255kbps [Sound Media Handler - MPEG-4 Audio]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch [Russian, Dub (Audio 1)]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch [English, Original (Eng) (Audio 2)]
Subtitle: UTF-8 [Russian, Rus (Subtitle 1)]
Subtitle: UTF-8 [English, Eng (Subtitle 2)]
```

Sample 2:

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 720x384 23.976fps ...
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch 313kbps [Sound Media Handler - MPEG-4 Audio]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch 317kbps [Sound Media Handler - MPEG-4 Audio]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch [Russian (Audio 1) [Default]]
Audio: AAC 48000Hz 6ch [English (Audio 2)]
Subtitle: VobSub [Russian (Subtitle 1) [Default]]
Subtitle: VobSub [Russian (Subtitle 2)]
Subtitle: VobSub [Russian (Subtitle 3)]
Subtitle: VobSub [Russian (Subtitle 4)]
```

ETC

Comment: Do those same files play on other players, such as VLC?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. All of a sudden MPC would not play MKV files. I tried resetting the settings, reinstalling it and updation my radeon drivers. Nothing. Even set my graphics card to default clocks in case it was the overclock. Nothing.The same file plays in VLC no problem. I was ready to tear my hair out. I did some snooping around in the settings.

I went to "Options" > "Playback" expanded the tree to see "Output". 
Under "Direct Show Mixer"  I changed "Enhanced Renderer" to "Video Mixing Render 9 (renderless)". 
Clicked "Apply", exited MPC and tried opening the file again. Voila! My MKV's and FLV's play once more!

So far no problems. I hope this can help those with similar issues.

My video card is an Radeon HD5770 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall MPC-HC and CCCP completely
2. Get the latest beta version of MPC-HC from https://nightly.mpc-hc.org/
3. Install the version you just downloaded and make sure to reset the settings while doing so.
4. Try playing an MKV again and report back.